# What is wrong with the && syntax here?

Tags: syntax

```
function lastfm_entity_update($entity, $type){
    if (isset($type)) && (entity_get_info($type) == 'subject') {

    };
};
```

I want to check if type exists and if the type is equal to subject, but the code is giving a syntax error.
Any ideas?

Comment: add an opening parenthesis just after the if and a closing one at the end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is not the "&&" operator, but your parentheses. What "if" syntax requires is

```
if (...) { .. }
```

but you wrote:

```
if (...) && (...) {}
```

see?

Just add another parentheses pair:

```
if ((isset($type)) && (entity_get_info($type) == 'subject')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:-

```
 if (isset($type) && entity_get_info($type) == 'subject') {
```

(brackets)

Answer (score 0):

try
 if (isset($type)) && ((entity_get_info($type) == 'subject'))